# Database flat file

Tags: database, hex, flat-file

I have a database on some flat files, the problem is that this files are filled with hex numbers, for example:

```
0001 0000 0000 524d 4b46 0002 0000 0002
0477 0797 0220 3002 2004 0800 0800 0000
```

and so on..

I only have this files the db structure and a connection string:

```
DSN=..;UID=..;PWD=...;DBQ=H;CODEPAGE=1252;
```

I would like to know whats the database system in order to connect via php code.
Is there anything i can do with just this information?